# issues with grep variable and white space

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I am trying to get this bit of code to work. and I am getting hung up on the second piped grep with the variable $pkgname. I am unable to find a way to get it to read the variable correctly either I get no output or as the code is currently written I get grep: illegal byte sequence. if I put either text with no space in the variable it works or I enter the text as part of the grep statement it works.

```
 #!/bin/bash
counter=0
results2=Executing\ SSH\ MOTD\ banner
pkgname=SSH\ MOTD\ banner
until [ $counter = 1 ]
do
    echo $counter
    echo $pkgname
    echo $results2
    result=$(grep "$(date +"%b %d")" /var/log/test.log | grep “$pkgname” | cut -d':' -f 4 | sed 's/^ *//g')
    echo $result
    if [ “$result” == “$results2” ]; then 
    counter=1
    fi
done
echo finished
```

so the log file line I am looking for looks like this.

> Tue Jun 28 10:58:57 machinename process: Executing SSH MOTD banner

Comment: Those quotation marks you are using around `$pkgname` look rather suspect.

Comment: You're using '66' (`“`) and '99' (`”`) quotes in `if [ “$result” == “$results2” ]; then` and elsewhere, rather than ASCII `"` quotes.  Don't use a word processor for programming; it will drive you crazy fixing what word processors do so that it does what the shell requires.

Comment: Thanks Jack  and Jonathan for the second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to

```
pkgname="SSH MOTD banner" # Here use quotes to avoid using \
```

As [[ @jack ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2584475/jack) rightly pointed out in this [[ comment ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812450/issues-with-grep-variable-and-white-space#comment76605788_44812450), you need the neutral quotation mark `"` for a variable to be expanded. That said you can simplify the regex to below

```
pkgname="SSH MOTD banner"
d=$(date +"%b %d")
result="$(awk -v FS=":" -v d="$d" -v pkg="$pkg_name" '{if($0 ~ date && $0 ~ pkg){sub(/^ */,"",$4);print $4}}' /var/log/test.log)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was in a hurry I did not use my regular editor and I caused myself frustration I did not need. Also thanks for the options for producing my script results.